# adding shared objects to catkin package

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
i'm writing a node that has to call some functions from a .so library. The node called `test_service_server` has to use functions from `libtest.so`. This lib is NOT a catkin lib, it was created outside of ROS entirely.

inside my `CMakeLists.txt` i have the following:

```
include_directories( ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} lib)
set(EXTRALIB_BIN ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libtest.so)
add_executable(test_service_server src/test_service_server.cpp)
target_link_libraries( test_service_server ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${EXTRALIB_BIN})
```

I still get the error: `no rule to make target`.

Can someone give me a few tipps about linking shared objects to catkin packages?

EDIT:
Just to explain my problem better:
I have a shared object lib with ca 200 functions my node needs. ( in the /lib folder of the package)
These functions are described in header files (ca. 10, in the /include folder of the  package).

I can't get the source of this library to try and build it as a catkin lib.
how do i properly link my .so in CMakeLists.txt?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208850/adding-shared-objects-to-catkin-package/) by [Reiner](https://answers.ros.org/users/22377/reiner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2015-05-08

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Reiner](https://answers.ros.org/users/22377/reiner/) on 2015-06-02**:
FYI: found a solution:
target_link_libraries( test_service_server ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libtest.so.1)
this use of target link libraries works perfectly, in case someone stumbles upon the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Even though @Wolf's answer should work for you, I'll add some references to earlier questions that asked the same thing:

- [Is it possible to create a catkin package to provide precompiled libraries?](http://answers.ros.org/question/66685/is-it-possible-to-create-a-catkin-package-to-provide-precompiled-libraries/)
- [export a prebuilt library in catkin](http://answers.ros.org/question/97606/export-a-prebuilt-library-in-catkin/)

The accepted answer to the second question also has some links to pkgs that do the same thing.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Reiner](https://answers.ros.org/users/22377/reiner/) on 2015-05-11**:
thanks, those two links were a huge help for me:)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume its a precompiled lib you have copied to your project folders /lib directory. If so you need to

```
link_directories(  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib )

target_link_libraries( test_service_server ${catkin_LIBRARIES} test )
```

Note:
`link_directories` specifies the path for your libs
`target_link_libraries` takes the library names without `lib` prefix and `.so` postfix.

Also note that this is only valid if its a somehow outside catkin created lib. If catkin creates the lib it won't put them in the lib folder of your project but into the devel/lib folder of your workspace so the workaround is different then...

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2015-05-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Reiner](https://answers.ros.org/users/22377/reiner/) on 2015-05-11**:
Yes, it is a precompiled lib, made outside of catkin.
i tried your method with link_directories, unfortunately with the result: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltest

**Comment by [Reiner](https://answers.ros.org/users/22377/reiner/) on 2015-06-02**:
sorry for the late comment,
i've got it running, though i still needed both the lib prefix and the so postfix